# Uma tabela do tipo enum no banco de dados consegue armazenar mais de um valor para um mesmo elemento?

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados

`public enum SitucaoEnum { INCLUSAO(1), CANCELAMENTO(2), ATUALIZACAO(3), FINALIZACAO(4); }`

Eu consigo salvar em uma coluna do type enum no banco de dados mais de um valor desse? Ou só é permitido exclusivamente o salvamento de um enum por elemento?

Answer (score 0):

Se usar tipos comuns do banco de dados, como int, string e etc, conseguirá gravar somente um valor por coluna. Para gravar mais de um valor, teria que usar tipos avançados como json, mas neste caso precisaria implementar um conversor do tipo enum para o tipo do banco de dados, fora outros ajustes. O ideal é utilizar uma lista de Enum no objeto pai, assim basta mapear como uma lista.